# how to update the next row value as same value of first row in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

In Jtable, if I set the value of the first row second column to 20, then the value of the second row second column should be updated to 20 (same value) automatically.

I tried in cell editor.. But I didn't know how to update the second row value automatically if first row is updated?

Can you please anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Listening for Changes to the Rows and Columns of a JTable](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/ValueEvent.html) Component may help you to perform your task using TableModelListener

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on the `TableModel` side as well:

- either by using a listener
- or by having a weird implementation of `setValueAt` method

Do not forget to fire the correct events from your `TableModel` as well

Comment: can u give small example? which listener need to use?